# WooCommerce: register product to categories is super slow

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I write an import plugin for woocommerce products. When I register a product to categories with `wp_set_object_terms` this takes up to 6 seconds. It's because of a very complex mysql query in `_wc_term_recount`. I already posted this as an issue at woocommerce github.

But now I need a faster solution to register a product to categories. `wp_set_object_terms` would make my import process at least ten times slower. I can't believe that there is no better solution.

Is there any other way to do that? Any tips?

best thanks in advance,
Helmut

Comment: This function is running with the transient wc_term_count, can you verify that it exist when you import ? Do you have woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items option set to yes during your tests ? Can you edit with some code that need to be faster ?

Comment: Please share your code. Without seeing it we can't really help.